# SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model - Kerberos/Claims Authentication

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, claims-based-identity, sharepoint-clientobject

I'm trying to read a value from a list in a remote SharePoint site (different SP Web App).  The web apps are set up with Claims Auth, and the client web app SP Managed account is configured with an SPN.  I believe Kerberos and claims are set up correctly, but I am unable to reach the remote server, and the request causes an exception: "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

The exception occurs in the line `ctx.ExecuteQuery();` but it does not catch the exception in the `if (scope.HasException)` instead, the exception is caught by the calling code (outside of the using{} block).

When I look at the traffic at the remote server using Wireshark, it doesn't look like the request is even getting to the server; it's almost as if the 401 occurs before the Kerberos ticket is exchanged for the claim.

Here's my code:

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(contextUrl))
{

    CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
    cc.Add(new Uri(contextUrl), "Kerberos", CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
    ctx.Credentials = cc;
    ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default; 

    ExceptionHandlingScope scope = new ExceptionHandlingScope(ctx);
    Web ctxWeb = ctx.Web;
    List ctxList;
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection listItems;

    using (scope.StartScope())
    {
        using (scope.StartTry())
        {

            ctxList = ctxWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Reusable Content");
            CamlQuery qry = new CamlQuery();
            qry.ViewXml = string.Format(ViewQueryByField, "Title", "Text", SharedContentTitle);
            listItems = ctxList.GetItems(qry);
            ctx.Load(listItems, items => items.Include(
                                item => item["Title"],
                                item => item["ReusableHtml"],
                                item => item["ReusableText"]));
        }
        using (scope.StartCatch()) { }
        using (scope.StartFinally()) { }
    }
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    if (scope.HasException)
    {
        result = string.Format("Error retrieving content<!-- Error Message: {0} | {1} -->", scope.ErrorMessage, contextUrl);
    }


    if (listItems.Count == 1)
    {
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem contentItem = listItems[0];

        if (SelectedType == SharedContentType.Html)
        {
            result = contentItem["ReusableHtml"].ToString();
        }
        else if (SelectedType == SharedContentType.Text)
        {
            result = contentItem["ReusableText"].ToString();
        }
    }


}
```

I realize the part with the CredentialCache shouldn't be necessary in claims, but every single example I can find is either running in a console app, or in a client side application of some kind; this code is running in the codebehind of a regular ASP.NET UserControl.

**Edit:** I should probably mention, the code above doesn't even work when the remote URL is the root site collection on the same web app as the calling code (which is in a site collection under /sites/)--in other words, even when the hostname is the same as the calling code.

Any suggestions of what to try next are greatly appreciated!

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason why you are not using the standard OM?

You already said this is running in a web part, which means it is in the context of application pool account.  Unless you elevate permissions by switching users, it won't authenticate correctly.  Maybe try that.  But I would not use the client OM when you do have access to the API already.

Comment: I need to be able to make calls across web applications, and across farms...I guess I can give up the cross farm functionality, but I'd prefer to keep it in.  It's actually running in a user control, not a web part, but I guess as far as it goes, there's little differnce here--they both run in the SPContext.  I suppose it's worth trying the server side api for the cross web-app call, since I'm using kerberos.  I'll give it a shot this morning.

Comment: Well, to follow up, I have not been able to make cross farm calls using the client OM in that environment.  I'm still not sure if it's an environment issue or something obscurely wrong with the way I'm doing it, so until I can set up a separate environment myself from scratch, I'm giving up on the cross farm stuff, and went back to using the standard server-side OM.